# UWP SplitView Panel & Separator system like Mail app

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm currently building app for Windows 10 using UWP, `XAML` and C#. I followed a tutorial for adding a `SplitView` control to my main page. But I have a problem in defining a Separator & Sub-Menu system for the menu Option in the SplitView Pane like this `Windows.Mail` app :

[image: mail]

So I want to completely clone the Mail app's menu for the purpose of learning : How to works Panes, SplitViews, StackPanels...

This is what I currently have in my `MainPage.xaml` :

```
<Page
    x:Class="EasyCleaner.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EasyCleaner"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="628" Width="970.5">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="5">

        <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="130" Margin="0 10 0 0">

            <SplitView.Pane>

                <StackPanel Background="Gray">

                    <Button Name="btnShowPane" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE00F;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="btnShowPane_Click"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="Message_Menu" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE715;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Message" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="Favorite_Menu" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE1CE;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Favorite" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="Settings_Menu" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE715;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">Content</Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>

            </SplitView.Pane>

        </SplitView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

But the final result looks like :

[image: final]

How do I make the smallest buttons at the bottom, the separator and sub-menu systems (and highlight next to submenu) in the menu?

Comment: I'm not sure if all your requirements can be fullfilled with the NavigationView but maybe you can have a look at it. It is a new control (you have to raise minimum target to Fall Creators Update). It makes building such a menu much easier but of course, building it manually gives you more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) control.

> The navigation view control provides a collapsible navigation menu for top-level navigation in your app. This control implements the nav pane, or hamburger menu, pattern and automatically adapts the pane's display mode to different window sizes.

It provides much richer built-in functionality compared to SplitView, and it is the [recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigation-basics) for the type of navigation you want to emulate (Mail).

NavigationViewItems, NavigationViewItemSeperator, and NavigationViewItemHeader, as well as footer options should greatly simplify navigation code over a custom solution.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I make the highlight on the left corner ? (Like the "inbox" I marked in the picture)

Comment: The highlight _should_ come naturally when that navigation item is selected. Both that and the animation between selections should be built in.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to define this location in the XAML designer in your grid. Add a new row, and column and made them intersect.
2. Next add a new border and specify this border by defining the number
   of column and row and column/row -span. You should end with a perfect
   area where you want to put your buttons in.
3. Now add a stackpanel with an horizontal orientation and put your
   buttons inhere.

Hope this helps.